# Insert data into mysql from sql file or using csv file

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-connector-python

I have an `db.sql` file and I tried inserting the data from it to my local MYSQL using the command:
`mysql -u root -p chitfund < db.sql` . It doesn't show any error and also doesn't print anything. But when I try to see the tables in my db, it shows now tables.  I have the data in the form of `.csv` also. I tried inserting using `mysql.connector` , but it is not installing and throws an error. Is there any other way to insert the data using the sql or csv files.

Comment: You need to include the database name in your command: `mysql -u root -p chitfund database_name < db.sql `

Comment: `chitfund` is the name of the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my `.sql` file. It didn't have any insert or create statements. I assumed it has the statements and the data is not being inserted. After having all the insert statements for inserting the data, it worked properly